# Timeout to a function Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout

I use Selenium with Chrome WebDriver on mobile mode, I got an element and I need to click on it.

When I click, A pop-up is visible, which is good for me, but the click function is still going.

It's stuck and doesn't finish.

Also, when I click the element, there is no new screen on the browser, just an object visible, this is why the click button is not getting any response and doesn't finish.

I want to wrap this click function with a timeout to finish after a couple of seconds.

This must run on a Windows and I can not open a new process/thread for it, just finish the call function and continue with the code.

This is an idea of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://webstie.com')
toggle_to_mobile() # THIS IS PRIVATE METHOD
element = driver.find_element_by_name("my_element")
element.click() # THIS IS STUCK
.
.
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post a minimal reproducible example, and include the actual url of the page, if publicly accessible.

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question, the website does not matter